# Javascript/jQuery - Change input button the background image when mouse down and up

Tags: javascript, html, button, background-image, mousedown

I want to change input button the background image when mouse down and up, but it don't work.

[image]

```js
function mousedown() {
  document.getElementById("enlarge_btn").style.backgroundImage = "url(../picture/image2.svg)";
}

function mouseup() {
  document.getElementById("enlarge_btn").style.backgroundImage = "url(../picture/image1.svg)";
}
```

```css
.button_img {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background-image: url(../picture/image1.svg);
  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input id="enlarge_btn" type="button" name="button" class="button_img" onmousedown="mousedown()" onmouseup="mouseup()">
```

Where can I fix?

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Your code [seems to be working](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/GRmZmgQ). Please elaborate on "it don't work" because [that's not really helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: because you change image source, I think problem is file path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find if I change

```
document.getElementById("enlarge_btn").style.backgroundImage = "url(../picture/image2.svg)";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("enlarge_btn").style.backgroundImage = "url(picture/image2.svg)";
```

It works, so the problem is file path.

Thanks.